# Публикация проекта с базой данных

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, git, github

Для работы приложения по обработке естественного языка (NLP) необходима база данных (MSSQL, содержит N-граммы из корпуса размеченных по тональности текстов, три таблицы, суммарно около 1 280 000 записей). Проект разрабатывается с использованием git и GitHub. В связи с этим возник вопрос, как было бы правильно выложить данную БД? Хочется, чтобы на GitHUb хранилась рабочая версия программы, но размер БД превышает 100 Мб, поэтому залить ее в основной репозиторий не получится. Какие есть варианты решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Экспортировать в `CSV` и сжать в архив?

Comment: @nobody Думал о подобном варианте. Конечно, вопросы, связанные с размером объекта решаются, но в таком случае появляется необходимость создавать отдельный скрипт для создания БД и записи в нее данных из CSV. Думаю, работать он будет весьма долго. Но на крайний случай вариант подходит, спасибо.

Comment: 100Мб - это не долго :) Вот это действительно долго: http://guvm.mvd.ru/upload/expired-passports/list_of_expired_passports.csv.bz2 :)

Answer (score 1):

Для Git есть [расширение](https://git-lfs.github.com/) git-lfs (large file storage).

GitHub [поддерживает](https://blog.github.com/2015-04-08-announcing-git-large-file-storage-lfs/)  его.

Его нужно локально [установить](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases), а потом:

```
git lfs track "large_file.txt"
```

а затем все как обычно.